# Can we use JQuery UI Dialog for complex operations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am trying to use JQuery UI dialog (modal form) for the following scenario. I have a search box and a drop down menu in modal form. User will be entering a term to search and will be choosing an option from drop down. Depending on the input, I make some REST calls. Now, I want to display the result of the REST call on same modal form. Is it possible to do this using modal? If there is a better solution for this, then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry for not being clear enough. Actually I am using Ruby for the back end part. i.e for REST calls and also for parsing. That is working fine. Once the user enters term to search in dialog, I am calling the Ruby method from which I get array of data to be displayed on the same dialog where user entered term to search. I am unable to do this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, for your rest calls, I assume your using jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.get` or `$.post` and I also assume your REST API is returning valid JSON,  you would have something like:

```
$.post('RESTURL',{action:'something'}, function(data) {
    $('#dialog').append(data.something);
}, 'json');
```

Sorry the example is so vague, you didn't provide much info.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I will edit my post. Actually I am using Ruby for the back end part. i.e for REST calls and also for parsing. That is working fine. Once the user enters term to search in dialog, I am calling the Ruby method from which I get array of data to be displayed on the same dialog where user entered term to search. I am unable to do this part. Looking at your example above, I added $('#dialog').append("Hello again"); to my code. I don't see Hello world being displayed in the dialog. Is it how I need to do?

Comment: It is working now. append was the method I was looking for. It worked after adding $('#dialog-form').append("Hello again"); Thank you.